# Permission denied when trying to install pandas with pip

Tags: python, windows, pandas, permissions, pip

I am trying to install the Python pandas package from the Windows command line with pip:

```
pip install pandas
```

but I get the following errror. I also downloaded the wheel version from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas/0.17.0/#downloads and tried that as well:

```
pip install pandas-0.17.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
```

In either case, I get this error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\adi\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pi
p\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2795, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "c:\users\adi\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pi
p\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2652, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\adi\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pi
    p\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2786, in _parsed_pkg_info
        return self._pkg_info
      File "c:\users\adi\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pi
    p\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2652, in __getattr__
        raise AttributeError(attr)
    AttributeError: _pkg_info

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\adi\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pi
    p\basecommand.py", line 211, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "c:\users\adi\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pi
    p\commands\install.py", line 294, in run
        requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
      File "c:\users\adi\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pi
    p\req\req_set.py", line 334, in prepare_files
        functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
      File "c:\users\adi\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pi
    p\req\req_set.py", line 321, in _walk_req_to_install
        more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
      File "c:\users\adi\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pi
    p\req\req_set.py", line 561, in _prepare_file
        set(req_to_install.extras) - set(dist.extras)
      File "c:\users\adi\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pi
    p\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2774, in extras
        return [dep for dep in self._dep_map if dep]
      File "c:\users\adi\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pi
    p\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2797, in _dep_map
        self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
      File "c:\users\adi\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pi
    p\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2819, in _compute_dependencies
        for req in self._parsed_pkg_info.get_all('Requires-Dist') or []:
      File "c:\users\adi\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pi
    p\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2788, in _parsed_pkg_info
        metadata = self.get_metadata(self.PKG_INFO)
      File "c:\users\adi\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pi
    p\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1616, in get_metadata
        return self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info, name)).decode("utf-8")
      File "c:\users\adi\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pi
    p\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1722, in _get
        with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\users\\adi\\appdata\\local\\
    temp\\pip-build-3ge1gj75\\pandas\\pandas-0.17.0.dist-info\\METADATA'
```

I also tried to open `cmd` as administrator, but still got the same error.

Meanwhile, I was able to install the numpy library using pip.

Comment: What about a simple: `pip install pandas`?

Comment: @DanielePantaleone same thing. I just updated my entire question so that it is more clear now.

Comment: Did you try `sudo pip install pandas` ?

Comment: @Fabio no, I am on a Windows machine.

Comment: Which version of pip are you using? Did you try upgrading to the latest version with `pip install pip --upgrade`?

Comment: @DanielePantaleone I am using pip 7.1.2. Just tried to upgrade it, and got the message that the requirements are already satisfied.

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar problem trying to install pandas on azure.

The following worked:

```
python -m pip install --user pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem even running cmd as administrator. I re-start the pc and run the cmd as administrator again and it worked.

For the record I tried to install though the Anaconda's Windows app, obtaining the same permission error.

Answer (score 0):

FOR ANYONE FINDING THIS NOW:

This website worked perfectly for me. Sadly, I had to use the built-in command prompt, but it gets the job done:
https://data-flair.training/blogs/install-pandas-on-windows/